# my form won't refresh back to initial state or navigate to the feeds page after success full registration i'm i wrong using async?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

my form won't refresh back to initial state or navigate to the feeds page after success full registration and now react is telling me Async await is only available in es8 please can i go about this i want the form to provide some kind of feedback after registration like to n avigate to the homepage and clear all field but it's not working

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
} from 'firebase/auth'

import { setDoc, doc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'

import { db } from '../firebase.config'
import OAuth from '../components/OAuth'


function SignUp() {
  
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
  })
  const { name, email, password } = formData

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    }))
  }


  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      const auth = getAuth()

      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      )

      const user = userCredential.user

      updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
        displayName: name,
      })

      const formDataCopy = { ...formData }
      delete formDataCopy.password
      formDataCopy.timestamp = serverTimestamp()

      await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), formDataCopy)

      navigate('/')
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error('Something went wrong with registration')
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='pageContainer'>
        <header>
          <p className='pageHeader'>Welcome Back!</p>
        </header>

        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='nameInput'
            placeholder='Name'
            id='name'
            value={name}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <input
            type='email'
            className='emailInput'
            placeholder='Email'
            id='email'
            value={email}
            onChange={onChange}
          />

          <div className='passwordInputDiv'>
            <input
              type='password'
              className='passwordInput'
              placeholder='Password'
              id='password'
              value={password}
              onChange={onChange}
            />

          </div>

          <Link to='/forgot-password' className='forgotPasswordLink'>
            Forgot Password
          </Link>

          <div className='signUpBar'>
            <p className='signUpText'>Sign Up</p>
            <button className='signUpButton'>
              Sign Up
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

        <OAuth />

        <Link to='/sign-in' className='registerLink'>
          Sign In Instead
        </Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default SignUp
```